# Where in Wiindows 10 is noted, that an installation process is running?

Tags: installation, blocked

An installation process for Java crashed.
When I try to restart the installation, I get the message that there is another installation still running.
Where is this flag and how can I reset it?

Comment: Did you try to stop Windows installer service?

Comment: I tried, but no effect. Somewhere must be a flag. Maybe in the registry

Answer (score 0):

Try the tip number 6 from https://windowsreport.com/another-installation-already-progress-error-windows-10/#6.

Run regedit. Then find the keys "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsInstallerInProgress" and "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionInstaller" and locate the Default value and double click it. Delete the values from Data value field.

After making changes to your registry, you need to set the Startup type of the Windows Installer service to Disabled. After that, restart your PC and set the Startup type for Windows Installer to Manual.

Comment: I cannot find the first key.

Comment: The 2nd key exists but has not the entries I should change